# jQuery selector for finding the <th> elements from _Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have the following table structure inside a view which gets displayed in the _Layout view in place of @RenderBody

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>first</th>
          <th>second</th>
          <th>third</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>1st</td>
          <td>2nd</td>
          <td>3rd</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

In my _Layout page, I want to apply the contextMenu event to the **th** elements, however, being a beginner, I'm having a hard time figuring the selector for the same.

Some combinations that I've tried -
I have a reference to my table in a variable called oTable

```
oTable.$('tr th').contextMenu ....

oTable.$('thead tr th').contextMenu ....

$('table.tableID th').contextMenu ....
```

None of them are working. Any suggestions?

Comment: `$('tr th')` works for me. Try `$('tr>th')` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to select ALL of your th elements then you don't need anything more complicated than this:

```
$('th').contextMenu ....
```

If your table has an id associated to it then the following will allow you to target just that table:

```
$('#yourid th')
```